# How to disable all previous dates on the datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've two date pickers for select the start date and end date. Once I pick a start date, I want to grey out all previous dates on the calendar for the end date field I tried the following code but its grey out previous dates with respect to current date

**script**

```
$("#startDate").onChange(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
    var startDate = new Date($(this).val());
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
    $("#hDate")[0].value = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
});

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    buttonImage: "../Images/calender.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showOn: "button",
    minDate: -($("#hDate")[0].value)
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Start" class="datepicker" id="startDate">
 <input type="text" placeholder="End" class="datepicker" id="endDate">
 <input type="hidden" id="hDate" value="">
```

how can I solve this

Comment: try with jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datepicker fires an `onSelect` event when a date is chosen. Use this event to set the `minDate` option in the other datepicker. Here is how:

```
$("#endDate").datepicker();
$("#startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var date = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);
        $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/6Fx54/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('#endDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('#startDate').on("change", function() {
       //Begin the re-creation
       $('#end-datepicker').datepicker( "destroy" );
       $('#endDate').datepicker({
                /**
                 * Set the date to be the same as the start
                **/
                minDate : $('#startDate').datepicker( "getDate" ),
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                //Optional: setDate: The same as minDate.
             });
        });
```